# Use Acronis True Image without Services?

Tags: windows-7, services, acronis-trueimage

is there a way to (manually) use Acronis True Image Home 2010 on Windows 7 without the services AcrSch2Svc and afcdpsrv (and other Acronis related services, if there are more)? Regards, tamberg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but you can run pre- and post-backup commands - I see no reason why you can't script (net start/stop) the running of these services for automated backups. Equally, if you don't schedule your backups, manually run the scripts before you do a backup.

If you don't schedule your backups then your can set AcrSch2Svc (the scheduling service) to manual anyway. I *think* the afcdpsrv service is used for producing incremental backups (judging by the CDP references) and is likely to be essential to the program. Does this mean it needs to run continuously? I doubt it, but you never know.

The simplest solution to your query would be to ask Acronis themselves. I've found their support service to be helpful and effective.

Out of interest, why do you want to stop these services? They aren't resource hogs, and you won't save much by stopping them. Do you have a clash with some other services/programs?

Comment: No clash so far. Just trying to reduce number of services.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to be in Windows to do what you need to do?

You can create a bootable media from within Acronis and use this to carry out your tasks.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you don't want that services run at startup so i suggest you to ues autoruns application (you can find it at filehippo.com) or you can just type msconfig to the "run" and you will see the programs runs at startup... but if you are using acronis to backup, why don't you use windows 7 's own back up software cause in win7 it is very easy and useful (i was using acronis but when i was using winXP) (((open control panel then choose 'backup and restore'then select 'create a system image' from left panel ...but if th services now shown in autoruns program or msconfig you should look  control panel--administrative tools--services--here you can find running services ((but caution if you don't know which service is for what program you should NOT close the service))

Comment: To be fair, the backup features including in Windows are basic at best.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take, if I really wanted to be non invasive... would be to not even install Acronis. Boot from an Acronis boot disk, make the image, and then boot the OS.

Acronis never gets installed, just used.